# make another partition bootable

Tags: upgrade, ssd, boot-partition

So I have my / on an SSD that decided to have a bad sector.

I don't know if there a way to copy the data on another partition on an HD that I already have but don't use yet and make it bootable?

Or... even with a bad sector (that what seams to be the problem when I want to log in tty), an upgrade of Ubuntu might help going over this bad sector?

I just don't want to lose my /home, so tired of restoring it with that awful back-up system.

Any ideas or suggestions are very welcomed here!

Answer (score 1):

First things first, because your hard drive may be failing, you should back up your data.

There are several strategies for backup

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem

Personally I use rsync https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync

Back up your home directory and any system files you edited.

Next you can try re-installing Ubuntu. It should not over write your data in your home directory.

> Since Hardy it is possible to reinstall Ubuntu without losing the content of the /home folder (the folder that contains program settings, internet bookmarks, emails and all your documents, music, videos and other user files). This can be done even if /home is not on a separate partition (which is the case by default if you did not manually separate it when installing Ubuntu originally).

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation

Answer (score 1):

If its one bad sector, I wouldn't worry about it.  But as more blocks become incapable of being written to from overuse the same thing happens. Eventually you'll start losing usable capacity though.

> Question
>
> My SSD has a lot of bad sectors. Do I need to replace it?
>
> Answer
>
> With a traditional hard drive, that is often the case, but with an SSD
>   things are a bit different. Due to the nature of flash technology it's
>   normal to have a small number of bad sectors on an SSD, and as long as
>   the number of bad sectors remains constant there is no reason for
>   concern. The firmware on the SSD keeps track of all bad sectors and
>   marks them as unusable. So even though the bad sectors are present on
>   the drive they never come into play, and data is never written to
>   them.
>
> The easiest way to keep track of the number of bad sectors on an SSD
>   is to run ChkDsk (short for "check disk") in Windows. After checking
>   the drive, ChkDsk will report the number of bad sectors it found.
>   Simply make a note of what that number is, and run ChkDsk again after
>   a couple of days.
>
> If the number of bad sectors remains the same, all is well.  If the
>   number of bad sectors is increasing over time, its time to replace the
>   drive.<sup>1</sup>

You can use [dd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd) to copy the data if you feel that you need to, and its a good idea, but as I stated, one bad sector is not bad, specially since manufacturers add spare sectors, just for this reason.

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Crucial](http://forum.crucial.com/t5/Solid-State-Drives-SSD-Knowledge/My-SSD-has-bad-sectors/ta-p/111486)</sup>